# how to see how much anti-virus takes from memory and CPU?

Tags: performance, anti-virus

when i open Windows Task Manager,  i see the anti-virus in some rows

how i can know the right row ?

what to look for ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no one answer as it depends on what antivirus you are using.

Most antivirus programs consist of at least two lines, one being the interface / control program and the other being the actual antivirus engine / service.

I recommend you use [Microsoft / Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), you should be able to sort via directory and find all the antivirus type processes.

[image]

However, in addition, the engine **MAY** (or may not) be hiding behind svchost.exe, so you will have to manually find that out for yourself as every antivirus engine is different

Comment: "it depends on what antivirus you are using", spot on.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to see how much performance you're losing to your AV, you're going about it the wrong way. Modern PCs have more than enough RAM and CPU - but disk read/write is still slow, and an always-on AV has to scan every single read and write, which can cause huge slowdowns.

I no longer run with an always-on AV - the detection rates for "real-world" threats (As in, discounting the many hundreds of viruses that aren't in existence today, and counting the hundreds of new ones made daily) are pathetic, and a little intelligence goes a long way for preventing the AV from having to do anything at all. A weekly, or even monthly, scheduled scan is enough.

Comment: or you can enable it only when you download...

Comment: Or that - indeed many browsers can automatically scan, which is a cool feature.